# When I create a "Portal Template", .ascx and .js files are not copied in DotNetNuke 5.6.1

Tags: templates, portal, dotnetnuke, ascx

When I create a "Portal Template", .ascx and .js files are not copied to template file(neither to xml nor to resource file)?

DotNetNuke version 5.6.1

Any ideas why? I hope it is some configuration problem?

Answer (score 1):

Are these .ascx and .js files *in the portal's directory*, or are you referring to the modules' files (in DesktopModules)?  DesktopModules aren't included in a portal template, you'll have to manually install any required modules for the portal template to work.  I would think you'll also have to do the same with skins/containers, but the portal template *may* get skins/containers that are specific to a portal.

If you're creating new DNN instances, you can put module packages in the /Install/Module folder, and they'll get automatically installed with DNN, and then be available to your portals.

Comment: When creating a new portal from portal template, all files (such as page.jpg, style-admin.css, page.doctype.xml) are copied to \portals\xx\skins\ except files with extensions .ascx and .js. 
images folder also created under that site skin.

What am I asking is, is this situation is related with my configuration(iis 5/ .net 4) or related with some limitation in dnn 5.6.1?

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure your skin package includes those files.

open dnn file in your skin package and make sure you have entry for these files.

Best way is to create package by using create package wizard.

You have to go to Host > Extensions > edit your skin and at the bottom right you will find link for create package wizard